# Blender Gradient (using nodes) not working when exporting file to glb file format

Tags: node-editor, export, gltf

[image]

I have created the following gradient in blender and it works as expected (in blender). When I export it to glb though, there is no gradient anymore but just one gray shade. How could I fix that?

Comment: Arbitrary nodes must be baked to textures prior to using them in glTF / GLB.  For more information, see: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html